# Objective C memory management in between two methods

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

i m little confused on memory management in following scenario

```
-(NSData *)getData{ 
    NSData *TempData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    return TempData; 
  }

 //in some other method
 NSData *NewData = [self getData];
```

now the question is till when NewData will be retained and how should i release it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong usage of this getter method.
It should return an autoreleased copy of NSData. The autoreleased copy may or maynot be retained by the caller. Incase it is retained, its the caller's responsibility to release it.

Secondly a typo in return of this method, it should be NSData*.
My typo in return. Thanks to Peter Sarnowski for pointing.

```
-(NSData *)getData { 
    NSData *tempData = [NSData data];
    return tempData; 
}
```

The caller can retain it by using the following code:

```
NSData *myData = [[self getData] retain];
//Some code

[myData release];
```

In case caller is not interested in retaining this object, he will just call

```
NSData *myData = [self getData];
```

and use within the same function from where it is called.

Comment: you should return TempData - the object, not NSData. Your example will not compile even.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code from

```
-(NSData)getData{ 
    NSData *TempData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    return NSData; 
 }
```

to

```
-(NSData)getData{ 
    NSData *TempData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    return [TempData autorelease]; 
 }
```

or release it just by code

```
[NewDate release];
```

and I think the problem is in your getter method.
It is not returning the TempData you retained.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `release` when you're done with the object:

```
-(NSData *)newData{ 
    NSData *TempData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    return TempData; 
}

//in some other method
NSData *NewData = [self newData];

// use data

[NewData release];
```

*EDIT*: In order to conform to the convention, the method that returns the retained object should start with `new`.  Thanks to  @PeterSarnowski.

Comment: This is against the convention and guidelines and is likely to cause leaks sooner or later. Better to modify the getData method to return an autoreleased object.

Comment: @PeterSarnowski if i use autoreleased object then how i m supposed to retain it in `NSData *NewData = [self getData];` for usage in that function

Comment: @PeterSarnowski Agreed; this can be fixed by naming the method `newData`, however to conform to the convention.

Comment: @Yadnesh are you sure you need to retain the object? An autoreleased object will not get released inside of your method if you got a pointer that's pointing to it. You only need to retain the object when you want to 'keep it for later' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It will stay alive till you call [newData release], your method returns a object with a retain cout of 1 because of the alloc, this means according to the cocoa memory managament rules that your method should start with new or alloc or contain copy, so change the method name to newData.